# How to open a file with all folds opened?

Tags: folding

I've got the following line in my `_vimrc` file which enables folding for my PHP (and other) files:

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

However, whenever I open a file it starts with every fold closed, but I would like the file to start with its folds open.

How can I execute the command `zi` to open up folds when vim 7.4 is launched?

I tried putting this in the `_vimrc` but I get a pop up window with the error message:

```
E492: The following is not an editor command: zi
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8316139/2558252

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`zi` inverts the option `foldenable`. But you don't want to invert it, you want to disable it. So put the following in your .vimrc:

```
set nofoldenable
```

Answer (score 7):

[Add the `foldlevel` option to your _vimrc:](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file)

```
set foldlevel=20
```

This opens 20 levels of folds automatically when you open a file.

I am not familiar with the `zi` command, I just know `zR` to open all folds from normal mode. In your _vimrc, you generally cannot use normal mode commands to my knowledge.

Comment: `:help zi` plus scrolling up a bit in the help was a useful read. One more command learned :)

Comment: You can use normal mode commands in vimrc with `autocmd`. Also, the [article you refer to](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file) suggest [using `zR` with `autocmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316817/9157799).