# How to prevent folding when Vim is launched?

Tags: vimrc, folding

I added `set foldmethod=syntax` to my `.vimrc`, but it automatically folds whenever a new file is opened. Is there a way to prevent auto-folding and just use `za` to toggle?

Comment: Thanks @grodzik [your link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4494/7621) solved my problem! However, not sure about the duplication.  Should I delete this one or keep it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I need `nofoldenable` in `.vimrc` too:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set nofoldenable
```

Comment: You might find `'foldlevelstart'` more useful.

Comment: @Antony do you suggest using `set foldlevelstart=99`? Does it make any difference compared to `nofoldenable`? Couldn't find any advantages...

Comment: It's a global option that specifies the starting `'foldlevel'` when editing a new file. `'foldenable'` is window local and toggles folds on or off.. You can of course use both and toggle `'foldenable'` with `zi`.